# How to print in dictionary and what is this structure in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering why we need this structure(?) in JS and how we're printing hello world in dictionary

```
const fun = () => {     
    return { // Q: Is this called dictionary? How can I access to this?
        matter: panging => { // Q: What's the purpose of having function here? how do we call it?
            'the most'; // what's doing here?
            console.log('hello world'); //How can I print this?
        }
    };  
};
```

How do we print hello world in this function, `fun`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no dictionaries in Javascript. What you have there is an object with a `matter` property. Call it with `fun().matter()`. `fun` will return an object, and then you can access (and call) the `matter` property:

```js
const fun = () => {     
    return { // Q: Is this called dictionary? How can I access to this?
        matter: panging => { // Q: What's the purpose of having function here? how do we call it?
            'the most'; // what's doing here?
            console.log('hello world'); //How can I print this?
        }
    };  
};
fun().matter();
```

The `'the most'` line does nothing at all; you could substitute it with any other expression (without side-effects) and you wouldn't see any difference.

Another way of looking at it:

```js
const fun = () => {     
    return { // Q: Is this called dictionary? How can I access to this?
        matter: panging => { // Q: What's the purpose of having function here? how do we call it?
            'the most'; // what's doing here?
            console.log('hello world'); //How can I print this?
        }
    };  
};
const returnedObj = fun();
returnedObj.matter();
```

Comment: Interesting. Why can't we just access the object like `fun().matter`?

Comment: Sure, you can do that - you'd just be accessing the function itself, rather than calling it. Eg `setTimeout(fun().matter, 1000);` would be perfectly valid